# Work out all the automorphisms of $C_7$. Now using a semidirect product, construct a nonabelian group of order 21

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I know that ${\rm Aut}(C_7$) is $C_6$, and ${\rm Aut}(C_6$)= $C_4 \times C_2$ but I do not know if that will help.

Any hints or tips welcome!

Comment: You want a semidirect product of $C_7$ with $C_3$, which means you need to find a homomorphism from $C_3$ into $Aut(C_7)$.

Comment: Use `${\rm Aut}$` for ${\rm Aut}$.

Comment: Note: $${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n),$$ where $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

Comment: which subgroup must be normal?

Comment: Well, there are no nontrivial maps $C_7\to\mathrm{Aut}(C_3)$ (because $\mathrm{Aut}(C_3)$ has order $2$); so the only action of $C_7$ on $C_3$ is trivial. You must, therefore, want $C_3$ to act on $C_7$. The normal subgroup is the one being acted on.

Comment: It is definitely not true that ${\rm Aut}(C_6) = C_4 \times C_2$.

Comment: [This](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C7sC3.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. To construct a semidirect product of 2 groups $A$ and $B$ you need a homomorphism $\psi:A\to Aut(B)$. In your case $A=C_{3}$ and $B=C_{7}$. So, you can pick an homomorphism $\psi: C_{3} \to Aut(C_{7})\cong C_{6}$ that maps $x$ to $x^{2}$. If you are ok with presentations, then you can define it as $G = C_{7}\rtimes C_{3} = \langle x, y \mid x^3=1, y^7=1, yx=xy^2\rangle$.

Actually, it does not matter what (nontrivial) homomorphism you pick (because you will get an isomorphic group). For further information you can read [this](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{Aut}C_7\cong C_7^×\cong C_6$.  So there are $6$, each of the form $\phi(g)=g^k$ for $k$ relatively prime to $7$.

$C_7\rtimes_\varphi C_3$ where $\varphi:C_3\to C_6$ is a nontrivial homomorphism, will be a nonabelian group of order $21$.

Comment: Not for *any* homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks @the_fox